# Moving one element without moving others [Android ADT]

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm currently developing an android app and I'm just wondering if there is a way to move the elements around on the graphical view without moving other elements around.

It's really a pain to get everything lined up the way I want it when moving one edittext moves 3 others too.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will depend on what your layout is so the simple answer is no. With certain layouts and attributes it might work but everything kind of depends on everything else.

If you're using a `RelativeLayout` then a `View` will be positioned relative to certain other views so this will cause problems.

If it's a `LinearLayout` then moving one to the top is going to move other things.

**Solution**

Do yourself a favor, learn to design them in the xml and don't use the graphical editor to place the `Views`/`ViewGroups`. I use the graphical tab **only** for checking how it looks. Using xml is easier and more flexible, IMHO

Comment: Well, that stinks lol. Thank you for the fast and helpful response!

Comment: Trust me, once you start doing it in the xml tab you won't want to mess with the GUI. And it isn't difficult at all.

Comment: Any good tutorials? I've been googling for them but I can't find one that explains it well. I'm trying to tinker around on my own but I'm not having much luck.

Comment: [Vogella](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vogella.com%2F&ei=9x6bU9OwBYWnyASZgYG4AQ&usg=AFQjCNFqANzqu8ap-e9CrG3QIqvAzXJvdg&sig2=q-VHAaK9mdBoU7Kz8Zidng&bvm=bv.68911936,d.aWw) is sometimes good for beginners. Or going through [the Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#write) can be quite helpful.